# When trying to stick to right aligned form label pattern, how do you handle multi-line labels?

Tags: forms, labels

I'm using 2 column right-aligned labels/left aligned input fields. For 99% of my app, it's great. It follows one of Luke Wroblewski's [quickest path to completion patterns](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?504). The problem is while trying to follow this pattern, multiline labels get hard to read if the label wraps more than 2 lines.
[image: multiline right aligned form labels]

Is it okay to make an exception for these labels in an attempt to have a better user experience? I'm thinking that left-aligned would be better for readability.

Comment: First try to align at the bottom the label and the radio buttons. It will be more natural while the reading. The answer will be connect to the question and there is no muscular work for the eyes of your users. In second time try to make shortest question don't forget "don't make me think" or "less is more" postulate. Here the user has a long long long question....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option would be to create a pattern where you keep labels in the format of section titles and move any questions that need to be read to to the column with the form elements.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm with you on leaving it consistent, but I also love your solution using section labels. I'll run it by the rest of the UX group and see how they feel about switching up patterns at the end of the form.

Comment: This seems to make the most sense in your context because the "labels" you provide are in full question form. When I think of labels, I think of short sentence fragments or a single word. I use this same pattern on my forms, providing a large sentence fragment label and a smaller description paragraph underneath/beside. That has seemed to improve user experience as it 1) looks better, and 2) the form is easier to scan.

Comment: Happy to help! I hope your form is well used. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it consistent with the rest of the form. It's not too difficult to read, in my opinion. If it was substantially longer I might look for a different text treatment.

My advice: keep it consistent and right aligned.